# Turbo Pascal assign() function to c++

Tags: c++, pascal

Is there a similar function to Turbo Pascal's `assign(out f:file, const Name)` function which assigns a name to a file in c++ without opening the file?

Comment: No there's not.

Comment: Turbo Pascal's `file` type is not nearly the same as C's `FILE` type. And, as @lurker said, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Pascal has an older language construct where you “bind” identifiers to external system resources. Borland (Turbo Pascal) never really implemented the concept beyond what you find in the file access routines.

Most modern languages follow the C-style methodology, in large part because almost all modern operating systems follow the Unix-style file/character device/etc design.

Either way, ask yourself what exactly you are trying to accomplish, then figure out how to do it using idiomatic C++. The C++ way really is more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

[As you can see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream), C++ does not have a way in the standard library to create a file stream, give it a file name and then open it. The open action uses a file name.

You can create an file stream that is not open yet, but it won't have a file name.